# Agregar options de un select a un elemento textarea

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy tratando de crear un `select` que al darle clic a la opción dicha opción o el `value` de la opción se vaya a mi textarea.

Traté de hacerlo con un `v-on:click` desde el `option` pero no me funciona, así que agregué un `v-on:change` en el `select` para que me pudiese ejecutar el método. El problema es que estoy mostrando los datos en un bucle `for` y evidentemente de la forma que lo estoy haciendo la variable `value` se llena con el último valor del bucle. Además pueden ver que con la opción que estoy intentando agregar el texto es con Javascript, sería interesante saber si se puede hacer con Vuejs y que el texto nuevo no me reemplace al anterior.

```html
<div id="app">
  <p v-on:click="addToText()">{{message}}</p>
  <select name="" id="tt" v-on:change="selectToText()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="value = option">{{option}}</option>
  </select><br>
  <textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      message: "VueJS",
      options: ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'],
      value: ""
    },
    methods: {
      selectToText() {
        document.getElementById('textarea').value = this.value;
        console.log('added');
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Para acceder a los elementos del DOM a través de VueJS no es necesario que uses métodos como `getElementById()`.
- Lo que deberías usar es la directiva `v-model` para vincular a un elemento del DOM con una clave del objeto `data` en tu instancia
- Entonces tanto para el `textarea` como para el `select` deberás tener una clave
- El evento efectivamente como lo mencionas es `change` el cual debe ir en la etiqueta `select` por tanto al momento el uso de `click` se puede descartar totalmente
- Para lograr que los elementos se vayan acumulando en el `textarea` y no se sobre escriban entonces necesitas la sintaxis de: `textarea += valorObtenido`

Código:

```html
    <div id="app">
      <select v-model="listado" @change="agregaElemento">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option  v-for="option in options">{{option}}</option>
      </select><br>
      <textarea v-model="recipiente" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
    <script>
      let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          options: [
            'elemento1',
            'elemento2'
          ],
          listado: '',
          recipiente: ''
        },
        methods: {
          agregaElemento () {
            this.recipiente += `${this.listado}-`
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
```

**Referencia**

- [directiva `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model)